# saveURI not working

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am trying to save the favicon from the webpage a user visits locally through a firefox-addon. I am storing the URL of the favicon as a nsIURI and trying to use the saveURI method but its failing on the persist.saveURI line. Below is my current code.

```
var path = "/home/testing.ico";             

var uri  = Cc['@mozilla.org/network/standardurl;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIURI);

var file = Cc['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile); 

var persist = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"]
.createInstance(Ci.nsIWebBrowserPersist);

uri.spec = tab.activeTab.url + "favicon.ico";

file.initWithPath(path);

persist.saveURI(uri, null, null, null, "", file, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, `nsIWebBrowserPersist.saveURI` expects 7 parameters and you are only passing 6 (missing the last one).

> **saveURI()**
>
> Save the specified URI to file.
>
> ```
> void saveURI(
>   in nsIURI aURI,
>   in nsISupports aCacheKey,
>   in nsIURI aReferrer,
>   in nsIInputStream aPostData,
>   in string aExtraHeaders,
>   in nsISupports aFile,
>   in nsILoadContext aPrivacyContext
> );
> ```

This [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=820522) is also related to this issue

Comment: I added "null" for the aPrivacyContext parameter but the image when I click on it says "Could not load image for 'testing.ico'. Any ideas?!??!

Comment: GOT IT! Used https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Miscellaneous#Saving_an_arbitrary_URL_to_a_local_file and it worked :)